# Saving a dictionary of dataframes in Databricks DBFS

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, databricks

I created a dictionary of data-frames after processing good amount of data. In order to avoid repeating this step again and again, i want to save the dictionary on Databricks dbfs and load it back as when required. I can see some suggestions asking to convert each key as dataframe back and save them back individually, but this doesn't serve the purpose when there are too many keys/dataframes. Please suggest a way around.

Comment: pandas or pyspark dataframes? you could `concat` the dataframes and use the keys as the index, assuming you have access to a datalake, you could save your data as parquet and load it up next time. It's hard to say without knowing what the full tech stack is ?

Comment: I was talking about pysapark dataframe. Concat/union is taking ages to execute given the data size. Pandas allows to save the dictionary  via Jupyter but not sure how this works on databricks